Select value from either of two tables (via foreign_key or directly)
I need to check for a value in either table_one or table_two.
In table_one the value is stored as foreign_key referencing table_three, and in table_two it is stored directly.
Pseudo code:
SELECT T1.*
    FROM table_one T1
    JOIN table_three T3 ON T3.id = T1.foreign_key
    WHERE T3.field = 'value'
OR
SELECT T2.*
    FROM table_two T2
    WHERE T2.field = 'value';

I also need to know from WHICH table the value is actually selected.

Help us help you - share some sample data and the response you'd like to get for that sample

The tables are way too complex to add here ... therefore the simpliiyed version. What is it that you don't get specifically?

For the simplified tables, what output do you expecT?

Either T1.* OR T2.*

What is the query supposed to return exactly. Typically, you don't need T1.* and T2.* Show minimal table definitions and your version of Postgres. (Are T1 and T2 compatible?)

This is not an SQL syntax issue. It is an operator issue, starting with an incomplete description of the problem and the desired result. Provide a complete description of what you want to happen and then folks can come up with a solution.


I need to check for a value ..

But then you show pseudo-code retrieving whole rows, which is different. No clarification. This just retrieves an ID:
(
SELECT 't1' AS source, t1.id
FROM   table_one t1
JOIN   table_three t3 ON t3.id = t1.foreign_key
WHERE  t3.field = 'value'
LIMIT  1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT 't2' AS source, t2.id  -- must be compatible row type
FROM   table_two t2
WHERE  t2.field = 'value';
LIMIT  1
)
LIMIT  1;

All parentheses required.
This is a single query. The return type of both SELECT statements must be compatible. I just pick the ID column from each in the hope their type matches. Adapt accordingly.
It's unclear whether either table can have multiple matches. I added LIMIT 1 to each to be safe.
Precedence between both tables is also unclear. Typically, this query returns a row from T1 first. There is no formal guarantee, but that matches the unspecified request.
Related:

Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?

If you actually need T1.* or T2.* (I doubt it.) and both are not compatible, there are awkward workarounds (barely ever needed), or else possible concurrency issues if you run two separate queries.
